# how to change the text to just the app name

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout

I m creating an application that allows the user to choose an application that is already installed on there phone, I got a listview populated with all the apps on the phone but everything appears and most of the names dont look right, like "com.android.launcher"

I just want all the apps names appearing like the "safety.app" in the picture and not the rest of them like the "com.android.launcher".

I am currently using the code "packageInfo.packageName" to get the list of apps

Does anyone know how to just get the names of the apps to appear here?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();

Comment: I just came across [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon) post on a website, sounds like what you are trying to do.